Understanding pytorch performance
I am running code to pass an input image (as pytorch tensor) through a convolutional network (torchvision.models.segmentation.deeplabv3_mobilenet_v3_large() with a modified head). On the returned output tensor I perform a bit of post-processing. Surprisingly, the post-processing (applying non-maximum suppression) takes longer than the inference itself:
#run inference
pred = my_deeplap_based_network(input)

#create a max pool operation
R = 9
self.maxpool = torch.nn.MaxPool2d(2*R+1, stride=1, padding=R, ceil_mode=True)

#run non-maximum-suppression. "pred" is a kind of heatmap and I want to suppress all non-max pixels:
nms = self.detected_points_nms(pred)

def detected_points_nms(self, pred, thresh = 0.3):
        predmax = self.maxpool(pred)
        max_mask = torch.logical_and(pred == predmax,pred > thresh)     
        detected_points = torch.zeros_like(pred)
        detected_points[max_mask] = pred[max_mask]
        return detected_points

The input and output tensor shape (BxCxHxW) is 12x3x512x512. Running this on a GTX 1080Ti takes ~25ms for the inference and ~75ms for the nms.
In my expectation, the nms operations should be much simpler (and thus faster) than the deeplab/mobilenet network. Is this assumption wrong, or am I doing something inefficient in my nms implementation?

how are you measuring performance? also max_mask = torch.logical_and(pred == predmax,pred > thresh) looks suspicious, have you made sure it returns what you're expecting?

for me indexing detected_points[max_mask] = pred[max_mask] looks suspicious. you may want to do something like detected_points = max_mask * pred, using the fact that multiplying anything by 0 will give you 0

Did you set the GPU-synchronized on measuring performance? Things could be random if those are not set.

Thanks for the hint regarding time measurement. I wasn't aware of the fact that Cuda calls are asynchronous and thus was measuring non-sense! After updating my timing code I get ~87ms for inference and ~21ms for the nms, out of which 19ms are for the maxpool operation. This is somewhat reasonable as I'm using a pretty large radius R=9. Reducing this e.g. to 5 significantly reduces the time required.

@dankal444 thanks for the answer! It turned out that my timing was bad and the indexing is actually fast, but your solution does work as well and seems (very slightly) faster
